# cv2.FeatureDetector_create('SIFT') causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.11 and python 2.7 for a computer vision project. 
I am trying to obtain the SIFT descriptors:

```
ima = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(ima,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create('SIFT') # or 'SURF' for that matter
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('SIFT')

kpts = detector.detect(gray)
```

When calling the last instruction it throws an ugly segmentation fault. I have to use a 2.4.x version, so uploading to the 3.x version of opencv to use SIFT or SURF methods is not an option. I have downgraded from 3.1 previously using sudo make uninstall and installed from 0 the actual opencv version.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: how did you install it ? (some pre-built versions do not contain non-free parts)

Comment: I compiled it on my machine, from the git repository

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import cv2

ima = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(ima, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detector = cv2.SIFT()

kp1, des1 = detector.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
```

`detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create('SIFT')` should also work for creating the SIFT object.

Comment: I have the same problem with crash but i applied the same code as you...

Answer (score 0):

currently I am beginner in Computer Science so apologize for my short explanation.
I have OpenCV 3 and Python 2.7.11
Before all I downloaded no no it's better that you read [this site](https://scivision.co/install-opencv-3-0-x-for-python-on-windows/)
after all you can write this code (It's almost the same of your code ).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lenna.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
detector = sift.detect(gray, None)

kpts, des = sift.compute(gray, detector)
# kpts,des=descriptor.compute(gray,kpts)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, kpts, np.array([]), color=255, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Install opencv_contrib using

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then your code will work.